# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at null:1, view.loadUrl("javascript:document

Tags: javascript, webview

I'm working on an app with a webview. In this webView I want to display a website. But this website has two frames. One for the menu and one for the content.

```
<FRAMESET border=0 frameSpacing=0 frameBorder=0 cols=181,*>
   <FRAME name="navi" src="navi_new.htm" target="mainframe" scrolling="auto">
   <FRAME name="_top" src="start.php" target="_self" scrolling="auto">
```

Within the webView I don't need the menu-frame. I want to block it. I tested the javascript functionality with: view.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Morning!')");  It works.

But I can't hide the frame:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName(\"navi\")[0].style.display = \"none\";");
```

I got the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at null:1
```

He shows both frames. Someone an idea to solve the problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is `view.loadUrl` actually interacting with the loaded page, or just executing the javascript by itself? Can you try executing `document.body.innerHTML` and seeing if it returns the loaded page content?

Comment: view.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.innerHTML.getElementsByName(\"navi\")[0].style.display = \"none\";");

Comment: I get:-------**Uncaught TypeError: Object** <frame name="navi" src="navi_neu.htm" target="Hauptframe" scrolling="auto"> <frame name="_top" src="start.php" target="_self" scrolling="auto"> <noframes> &lt;body&gt; &lt;p&gt;Diese Seite verwendet Frames. Frames werden von Ihrem Browser aber nicht unterstützt.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/body&gt; </noframes> **has no method 'getElementsByName' at null:1**